# Render a div in React with an initial scrollTop value set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component which is rendering a `div`. However I want this `div` to be rendered such that it's initially scrolled all the way to the bottom.

I know this can be achieved by using a `ref` and setting the `scrollTop` property in `componentDidMount` (or in `useEffect`), but this causes a flicker when the `div` is initially rendered.

If the `div` is rendered with the `scrollTop` property already set on the DOM Element, then the flicker will not occur.

React does not support a `scrollTop` property for the `div`. So is there any way to set an initial `scrollTop` value before the component is mounted?

Comment: Why would there be a flicker? `componentDidMount` is executed before browser updates the screen. Is it an async operation?

Comment: Actually, I'm using the `useEffect` hook, not `componentDidMount`, so that's why I'm getting a flicker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) hook to run some logic synchronously after all DOM mutations. These updates will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

```js
const { useRef, useLayoutEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current.scrollTop = ref.current.scrollHeight;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        height: 100,
        overflowY: "scroll"
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ height: 1000 }} />
      <div>Foo</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```